# allocating an object of abstract class type in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, abstract-class, subclass

I'm learning the inheritance and pointer right now, but when I try to run an simple example there shows an error. Here is my codes.

```
class car {
public:
    double getKM();
    void setKM(double kIn);

protected: 
   double miles;
   double km;
   virtual void convertMtoKM(double mIn) = 0;
};

class hybirdCar : public car {
public:
     hybirdCar(double a);
private:
     virtual void convertMtoKM(double mIn) override;
};

class electricCar : public car{
public:
     electricCar(double a);
private:
    virtual void convertMtoKM(double mIn) override;
};
```

I make a class named car, and have two subclass each is hybirdCar and electricCar and try to implement the abstract method from parent.

```
car:: car(){
    miles = 150;
}
double car::getKM() {
    return km;
}
void car:: setKM(double mIn){
    miles = mIn;
    if (mIn < 0) {
        miles = 0;
    }
    convertMtoKM(miles);
}

hybirdCar::hybirdCar(double a): car() {
    setKM(a);
}
void hybirdCar::convertMtoKM(double mIn) {
    km = (mIn*1.60934);
}

electricCar::electricCar(double a): car() {
    setKM(a);
}
void electricCar::convertMtoKM(double mIn) {
    km = (mIn*1.60934);
}
```

Here is the main method

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
int main () {
 vector<unique_ptr<car>> my_cars;
    my_cars.push_back(make_unique<hybirdCar>(100));
    my_cars.push_back(make_unique<electricCar>(60)); // shows an error like allocating an object of abstract class type 'electricCar' here
    my_cars.push_back(make_unique<hybirdCar>(80));

    for (int i = 0; i < my_cars.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Car " << i+1 << endl;
        cout << my_cars[i]->getKM()<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out ? I search some reasonable causes for the error, but I'm pretty sure I implemented the abstract method correctly.

Comment: The code you show [compiles for me](http://rextester.com/BRA97390). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in some code you haven't shown.

Comment: Please show the actual compiler error, and indicate the line of code it refers to.

Comment: Why is `convertMtoKM(double mIn)` a overridden method?